# array_unshift - how to put array the top with key name

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce, associative-array

I have array element stored in $sal to put at the start of an array $fields['billing']. i am using array_unshift for this purpose.

```
$sal = array(
    'label'       => __('Tratamiento', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', ''),
    'required'    => 0,
    'clear'       => true,
    'class'         => array('form-row  form-row-wide'),
    'type'        => 'select',
    'options'     => array(
        'Señor' => __('Señor', 'woocommerce' ),
        'Señora' => __('Señora', 'woocommerce' ),
        'Señorita'=> __('Señorita', 'woocommerce')
        )
     ); 

array_unshift($fields['billing'] , $sal);
```

array_unshift adding element at the start of array at 0 key index. after print_r i see:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Label] => Treatment
            [Placeholder] => 
            [Required] => 0
            [Clear] => 1
            [Class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form-row-row-wide form
                )

            [Type] => select
            [Options] => Array
                (
                    [Lord] => Lord
                    [Lady] => Lady
                    [Ms.] => Miss
                )

        )
```

My problem is only that i just want to change the key value from [0] to ['saluation'], i can simply do that with:

```
     $fields['billing']['saluation'] = $fields['billing'][0];
     unset($fields['billing'][0]);
```

but i also want it at the start of array. i tried many techniques but still unable to figure this out.

this is actully woocommerce fields arrays which i am dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by array_merge() function.

```
$fields['billing']= array_merge(array('saluation' => $sal), $fields['billing']);
```